# How can I determine the number of segments of a DASH MPD if duration and mediaPresentationDuration field is missing

Tags: mpeg-dash

How can I determine the number of segments of a DASH MPD, if neither duration field is available under period tag nor mediaPresentationDuration tag is present under MPD Header tag.

I have following dash mpd. how can I calculate total duration of all media segments available here.

Please find below the link for MPD, I am referring to.

[http://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/live/*definst*/bigbuckbunny/manifest_mvnumber_w1608158161.mpd](http://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/live/_definst_/bigbuckbunny/manifest_mvnumber_w1608158161.mpd)

Answer (score 0):

`MPD@type="dynamic"` means that this is a live stream, so there is no duration (but the live stream could end at some time of course).

Comment: Thanks Daniel for your response.

Comment: Then how can i calculate the number of media segments available to download corresponding to this mpd.

Comment: I'd recommend checking the MPEG-DASH specification, it explains very well how the placeholders (like here the `$Number$`) is calculated and replaced. It also has a section around segment availability timing. Those two details together should answer the remaining question.